# How to Create Speech Recognition Console Calculator in C#?

Tags: c#, console, calculator, voice-recognition

I have created a simple C# Console Calculator and i want to add Speech Recognition which will recognize the human voice.

Example:  if I want to add two numbers I will tell the program to add two numbers through my voice then it will do the calculation. But i don't know how to do it.here is the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        string operators;
        float ans;

        Console.Write(" first integer: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("enter a operator (+, -, /, *): ");
        operand = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("enter the second integer: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (operators)
        {
            case "-":
                answer = num1 - num2;
                break;

            case "+":
                answer = num1 + num2;
                break;

            case "/":
                answer = num1 / num2;
                break;

            case "*":
                answer = num1 * num2;
                break;

            default:
                answer = 0;
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(num1.ToString() + " " + operators 
                                 + " " + num2.ToString() + " = " + ans.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at [System.Speech.Recognition Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. You're going to need to include the `System.Speech` reference.
2. When the application is started up you'll need to issue the code to hookup the speech recognition. **Note that it's possible the `Text` property will already contain the expression you're expecting - something like `1 * 2` if you spoke `One times two`.**

## Code for Speech Recognition

```
SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();
rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    // parse the grammar here and perform your operations
    // write the result to the console
}
```